# ¿Se puede controlar el filtro de un Subformulario en Access por medio de botones?

Tags: ms-access, filtro

Tengo un `subformulario` de el cual, uno de los campos es "Talla" (Chica-Mediana-Grande).

El `subformulario` me muestra en automático toda la información de la tabla, pero quiero ver si hay forma de que a un lado del `subformulario` puedo poner 3 botones:

- un botón que diga "Talla Chica".
- otro botón que diga "Talla Mediana".
- y un tercer botón que diga "Talla Grande".

De tal forma que al presionar cada botón, mi `subformulario` solo muestre la talla correspondiente. Yo me imagino que es el control del filtro de ese campo en especifico, pero no he encontrado como hacerlo.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier orientación al respecto. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para el caso que estoy trabajando encontré la respuesta y la comparto por si a alguien le sirve el dato:

El código de mi botón quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
Private Sub Comando2_Click()
Me.SubCamisas.Form.Filter = "Talla='Chica'"
Me.SubCamisas.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Donde SubCamisas es mi subformulario (insertado dentro de mi formulario principal) y Talla es un campo de la tabla.

Los botones están también en el formulario y a cada botón únicamente se le va cambiando el filtro que necesita cada uno, em mi caso cambia de "Talla='Chica'" "Talla='Mediana'" "Talla='Grande'" Si observan las tallas al final o sea el "filtro" está en comillas simples por que se trata de un texto. Lo comento por que ahí batalle un poco y no encontraba cual era el error.